# get color code of specified x, y coordinates of Image Inside Scrollview

Tags: android, android-layout

basic game in which there are 2 Tracks(auto scroll) in which there is an object that will move on track. if the object move out of Track then Game over. 
[image: sample image]
[image: Sample image]
Layout:-

```
<FrameLayout>
           <ScrollView> <Track2/><Track2/></ScrollView>
           <ImageView>(Object)
         </FrameLayout>
```

Note : each Track resolution 1026*3000

app run on device which have resolution 1080*1080

Image on track let's say x=540 y=540

Scrollview is auto scroll by 3px,

to check every time "is object on Track or not ?" for that i try to match color code of Track border if color match Track border game over, but unable to get proper solution.

```
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/vertical_scrollview_id"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:fadingEdge="none"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/vertical_outer_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fm1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/track2" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/fm0"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/track1" >
            </FrameLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="72dp"
        android:layout_height="78dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/red_hexagon" />
</FrameLayout>
```

1. method move auto scroll

public void moveScrollView() {

```
    scrollPos = (int) (verticalScrollview.getScrollY() + 1.0);
    if (scrollPos == 1) {
        verticalScrollview.fullScroll(View.FOCUS_DOWN);
    }

    if (mRootLayout != null) {
        isTouchInView(mRootLayout, event);
    }
    verticalScrollview.scrollBy(scrollPos, -2);
}
```

2. check color code of track

private 
boolean isTouchInView(View view, MotionEvent event) {

```
        fmLayoutWidth = 1280;// mRootLayout.getWidth();

        fmLayoutHeight = 2289;// mRootLayout.getHeight();
        System.out.println("fmLayoutWidth---" + fmLayoutWidth
                + "--fmLayoutHeight--" + fmLayoutHeight);

        Bitmap bitmap = loadBitmapFromView(mRootLayout);
        System.out.println("isTouchInView -x---" + x + "--yyyyyy--" + y);

        int pixel1 = bitmap.getPixel(0, 0);
        int pixel2 = bitmap.getPixel(71, 77);
        int pixel3 = bitmap.getPixel(71, 0);

        int pixel4 = bitmap.getPixel(0, 77);
        String hex1 = convetRGBtoHexaDecimal(pixel1);
        String hex2 = convetRGBtoHexaDecimal(pixel2);

        String hex3 = convetRGBtoHexaDecimal(pixel3);
        String hex4 = convetRGBtoHexaDecimal(pixel4);
        System.out.println("----h1-----" + hex1 + "----h2-----" + hex2
                + "----h3-----" + hex3 + "----h4-----" + hex4);

        if (hex1.contains("#FFE400") || hex1.contains("#FFE50F")
                || hex2.contains("#FFE400") || hex2.contains("#FFE50F")
                || hex3.contains("#FFE400") || hex3.contains("#FFE50F")
                || hex4.contains("#FFE400") || hex4.contains("#FFE50F")) {
            score++;
        }
        tvScore.setText("" + score);
        return true;
    }

public Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
            Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(fmLayoutWidth, fmLayoutHeight,
                    Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
            if (viewObject != null)
                v.layout(mRootLayout.getLeft(), mRootLayout.getTop(),
                        mRootLayout.getRight(), mRootLayout.getBottom());
            v.draw(c);

            return b;
        }

private String convetRGBtoHexaDecimal(int pixel) {
        int redValue = Color.red(pixel);
        int blueValue = Color.blue(pixel);
        int greenValue = Color.green(pixel);
        return String.format("#%02X%02X%02X", redValue, greenValue, blueValue);
    }
```